# "Feature type :a unknown" exception in OWSLib WFS request

Tags: wfs, owslib

I have to script as shown below and request to get info on all features included in a feature.

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url="https://lacunaserver.se/geoserver/ows?")
print(wfs11.identification.title)
# [operation.name for operation in wfs11.operations]

print(list(wfs11.contents))


response = wfs11.getfeature(typename='adventuremap:badplatser',
                            bbox=(10.7154412374,53.8569329668,24.2974217818,68.2833889855),   
                            srsname='urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326')

out = open('data.html', 'wb')
out.write(bytes(response.read(), 'UTF-8'))
out.close()
```

However, every time I get the same error message:

```
"owslib.util.ServiceException: Feature type :a unknown"
```

What seems to be the problem in my script? I tried several WFS but they all return the same error.

Comment: which line returns the error?

Comment: The error comes after line: srsname='urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why (I lack the Python skills to debug) but it seems to be a version issue.

```
wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url='https://lacunaserver.se/geoserver/ows?')
response = wfs11.getfeature(typename='adventuremap:badplatser')
```

fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/owslib/feature/wfs100.py", line 249, in getfeature
    raise ServiceException(str(se.text).strip())
owslib.util.ServiceException: Feature type :a unknown
```

While this with Version 1.1.0:

```
wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url='https://lacunaserver.se/geoserver/ows?', version='1.1.0')
response = wfs11.getfeature(typename='adventuremap:badplatser')
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't explicitly specify a version number in your request, OWSLib will make a WFS 1.0.0 GetCapabilities request that is a request like:

https://lacunaserver.se/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0&

The WFS 1.0.0 specification doesn't allow more than one SRS to be advertised.  In this service the WFS 1.0.0 response tells us data is available in `<SRS>EPSG:3857</SRS>` but you have requested data as `urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326`, which is an error.

OGC WFS versions greater from 1.1.0 support more than one SRS, so if you want to request a feature in the non default SRS then you must explicitly request the WFS version in your OWSlib request.